# something like INotifyCollectionChanged fires on xml file changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, inotify, system.reactive

It's possible to implement INotifyCollectionChanged or other interface like IObservable to enable to bind filtered data from xml file on this file changed ? I see examples with properties or collection, but what with files changes ?

I have that code to filter and bind xml data to list box:

```
XmlDocument channelsDoc = new XmlDocument();
channelsDoc.Load("RssChannels.xml");
XmlNodeList channelsList = channelsDoc.GetElementsByTagName("channel");
this.RssChannelsListBox.DataContext = channelsList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a FileSystemWatcher

```
    private static void StartMonitoring()
    {
        //Watch the current directory for changes to the file RssChannels.xml
        var fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@".\","RssChannels.xml");

        //What should happen when the file is changed
        fileSystemWatcher.Changed += fileSystemWatcher_Changed;

        //Start watching
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    static void fileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.FullPath + " changed");
    }
```

Comment: I don't use Your advice in my project but thanks for info about this class, i test it and it really works, great watcher !!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement INotifyCollectionChanged on your own, to watch for file system changes use the FileSystemWatcher class in System.IO

Comment: I see that FileSystemWatcher is not too good idea in my project and try INotifyCollectionCHanged ;) Thanks!

Comment: So the changes are within your application and not by external programs changing a common file?

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlDocument` already raises `NodeChanged` events.  If you use an `XmlDataProvider` as your binding source, it listens to `NodeChanged` events and refreshes the bindings.  It also refreshes the bindings if you change its `Document` property.  Combine that with the `FileSystemWatcher` and you're on your way.

A simple example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication18.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data" XPath="/Data">
            <x:XData>
                <Data xmlns="">
                    <Channel>foo</Channel>
                    <Channel>bar</Channel>
                    <Channel>baz</Channel>
                    <Channel>bat</Channel>
                </Data>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Margin="50">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}, XPath=Channel}" />
        <Button Margin="10" 
                Click="ReloadButton_Click">Reload</Button>
        <Button Margin="10"
                Click="UpdateButton_Click">Update</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The event handlers:

```
private void ReloadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
    d.LoadXml(@"<Data xmlns=''><Channel>foobar</Channel><Channel>quux</Channel></Data>");
    XmlDataProvider p = Resources["Data"] as XmlDataProvider;
    p.Document = d;
}

private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlDataProvider p = Resources["Data"] as XmlDataProvider;
    XmlDocument d = p.Document;
    foreach (XmlElement elm in d.SelectNodes("/Data/Channel"))
    {
        elm.InnerText = "Updated";
    }
}
```