# Good examples of reading an XML feed every 10 min

Tags: c#, jquery, xml

I am looking for the best approach to update a website with live data every 10 minutes. I have been looking on the net, but cant really find a sample.

This is just a hypothetical situation for me. If I want to get live data from somebody and put it in my website what would the best way to do it?

An easy example is a sports score website that gets the scores data from some where else that provides live sports scores and your site displays live sports score changes.

Comment: Polling is not a best approach to start with.  Have you considered alternatives such as event driven design?

Comment: Can you provide more details?  How is the website updated from the XML?

Comment: I edited the question to a more specific example of what I am curious about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can probably do something like this (it's untested), but every 10 minutes you do a `HEAD-request` against the server, if the content of the XML-file is modified do a `GET-request` and process the data.

```
(function loop(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "HEAD",
            url: "/whatever"
            success: function(xhr, data){
                if(xhr.status === 304) {
                    loop();
                }
                else {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/whatever",
                        success: function(data){
                            // Process XML

                            // Run this function again.
                            loop();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        })
    // Run this every 10 min.
    }, 600000);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the XML file is local, perhaps this approach would be best:

[something like INotifyCollectionChanged fires on xml file changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504921/something-like-inotifycollectionchanged-fires-on-xml-file-changed)